# Can I hint to CUDA that it should move a given variable into the L1 cache?

Tags: cuda, ptx

Can I hint to CUDA that it should asynchronously move a given variable into the L1 cache?

I have a deterministic data access pattern (`crazy_access_order`) that is unfortunately very ill-served by an LRU cache eviction policy, which I think is what CUDA uses.
So, is it possible to tell CUDA to start loading a given variable into the L1 cache, so that it's (probably) available by the time I need it?

For example, I'd like `async_prefetch_to_l1` to exist so I could to write something like this:

```cpp
#define PREFETCH_DISTANCE 4

int crazy_access_order(const int i) { ... }

const MyType data[N] = {...};

// Warmup the first PREFECT_DISTANCE - 1 accesses.
for (int i = 0; i < PREFETCH_DISTANCE - 1; ++i) {
  async_prefetch_to_l1(&data[crazy_access_order(i)], sizeof(MyType));
}

// Do the computation.
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  // Start to fetch the data PREFETCH_DISTANCE steps into the future.
  async_prefetch_to_l1(&data[crazy_access_order(i + PREFETCH_DISTANCE)], sizeof(MyType));

  // Access the data that should already have been moved into the L1 cache.
  const datum = data[crazy_access_order(i)];

  // Do something with `datum`.
  ...
}
```

FWIW I've tried various full and partial loop unrolling schemes to give the compiler a full view of the data access order, and they don't seem to help much. I suspect the compiler isn't generating prefetch instructions, assuming they even exist.

EDIT:
It appears the `prefetch` PTX instruction, which is likely to compile to a `CCTL` or `CCTLL` SASS instruction, does tell the system to load the given data into the given cache (thanks to Robert Crovella). We also guess that `prefetch` can return before the prefetch is complete, as this would be consistent with the behavior of `LD` (load) instructions, but we're not sure.

EDIT 2:
I started using `prefetch` and immediately saw a 2x increase in performance (with a corresponding reduction in Long Scoreboard stalls).

Comment: I just found this `prefetch` PTX instruction: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-prefetch-prefetchu. Do you think that does what I want?

Comment: There's something called "Cache Control" (CCTL) in Ampere: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#ampere. It does seem to do prefetching, but the best documentation I could find is this patent application: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9639479B2/en. Search `.pf1 pre-fetch line into L1 cache`

Comment: @njuffa Believe me I've tried. I think there is a way to do it, but it involves partial recomputation and adds a lot of code complexity. It would be much better to get prefetching working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem to be possible to indicate a "prefetch to L1"  using the PTX prefetch instruction [you spotted](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-prefetch-prefetchu).

Here is a simple test case:

```
$ cat t2125.cu
#include <cstdio>
template <typename T>
__device__ void pfL1(T *a){
    asm("prefetch.global.L1 [%0];"
        ::"l"(a));
    return;
}

__global__ void k(float *r){

  pfL1(r);
  printf("%f\n", r[0]);
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_80 -c t2125.cu
$ cuobjdump -sass ./t2125.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_80
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_80
                Function : _Z1kPf
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM80 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM80)"
        /*0000*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R1, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x28] ;      /* 0x00000a00ff017624 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc400078e00ff */
        /*0010*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R2, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x160] ;     /* 0x00005800ff027624 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe200078e00ff */
        /*0020*/                   ULDC.64 UR4, c[0x0][0x118] ;                 /* 0x0000460000047ab9 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe20000000a00 */
        /*0030*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R3, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x164] ;     /* 0x00005900ff037624 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe200078e00ff */
        /*0040*/                   IADD3 R1, R1, -0x8, RZ ;                     /* 0xfffffff801017810 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc80007ffe0ff */
        /*0050*/                   CCTL.E.PF1 [R2] ;                            /* 0x000000000200798f */
                                                                                /* 0x0001ea0000000100 */
        /*0060*/                   LDG.E R0, [R2.64] ;                          /* 0x0000000402007981 */
                                                                                /* 0x000ea2000c1e1900 */
        /*0070*/                   IADD3 R6, P0, R1, c[0x0][0x20], RZ ;         /* 0x0000080001067a10 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe20007f1e0ff */
        /*0080*/                   UMOV UR4, 0x0 ;                              /* 0x0000000000047882 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe40000000000 */
        /*0090*/                   UMOV UR5, 0x0 ;                              /* 0x0000000000057882 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe20000000000 */
        /*00a0*/                   IADD3.X R7, RZ, c[0x0][0x24], RZ, P0, !PT ;  /* 0x00000900ff077a10 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe200007fe4ff */
        /*00b0*/                   IMAD.U32 R4, RZ, RZ, UR4 ;                   /* 0x00000004ff047e24 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe2000f8e00ff */
        /*00c0*/                   MOV R5, UR5 ;                                /* 0x0000000500057c02 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe20008000f00 */
        /*00d0*/                   F2F.F64.F32 R8, R0 ;                         /* 0x0000000000087310 */
                                                                                /* 0x004e640000201800 */
        /*00e0*/                   STL.64 [R1], R8 ;                            /* 0x0000000801007387 */
                                                                                /* 0x0021e80000100a00 */
        /*00f0*/                   MOV R20, 0x0 ;                               /* 0x0000000000147802 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fe40000000f00 */
        /*0100*/                   MOV R21, 0x0 ;                               /* 0x0000000000157802 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc80000000f00 */
        /*0110*/                   CALL.ABS.NOINC 0x0 ;                         /* 0x0000000000007943 */
                                                                                /* 0x001fea0003c00000 */
        /*0120*/                   EXIT ;                                       /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                                /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
        /*0130*/                   BRA 0x130;                                   /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
        /*0140*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*0150*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*0160*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*0170*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*0180*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*0190*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01a0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01b0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01c0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01d0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01e0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
        /*01f0*/                   NOP;                                         /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
                ..........



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_80
code version = [7,4]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

The instructions here:

```
        /*0050*/                   CCTL.E.PF1 [R2] ;                            /* 0x000000000200798f */
                                                                                /* 0x0001ea0000000100 */
        /*0060*/                   LDG.E R0, [R2.64] ;                          /* 0x0000000402007981 */
```

seem to correspond to the prefetch request, followed by the load of `r[0]` into R0, in preparation for the call to `printf`.

Although I happened to compile for cc 8.0, I observe the CCTL.E.PF1 instruction present when I compile for architectures all the way back to cc 5.2 at least, on CUDA 11.4.

So you can try that to see how it works for your code.

Comment: Do you think the `CCTL` and `CCTLL` SASS instructions return immediately, or do you think they return only after the prefetching is complete? I.e. are they synchronous or asynchronous? I'm not able to find any good documentation for them.

Comment: I'm not aware of good documentation for them.  However, ordinary loads in CUDA are "fire and forget".  Stated another way, a LD instruction, by itself, can never cause a warp to stall.  So this does not mean that the LD instructions returns in 1 cycle; it has some latency.  But the LD instruction, by itself, does not guarantee that the register is populated when it is finished - that is tracked separately by a scoreboard mechanism.  I'd be very surprised if the CCTL instruction somehow behaved differently ("synchronous" as you say).  But I can't cite chapter and verse of documentation.

Comment: Of course, CCTL does behave differently, presumably.    It has nothing to do with registers or register tracking, of course. In an analogous fashion, I would expect that the CCTL instruction has a certain nominal latency (typically less than 10 cycles) and does not guarantee that the L1 cache is populated when it is "finished".  Again, guessing here.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! Can you tell me how you know the destination register might not be set by the time an LD instruction returns? I can't find any good documentation of the semantics of PTX instructions. Also, do you know of any way to tell if a value is stored in L1, short of just timing it?

Comment: We're getting tripped up with terminology that I'm not comfortable with.  For independent confirmation of LD behavior, see page 11 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf).  I don't know of a way to tell what is in L1, except via some indirect microbenchmarking latency experiment.  The paper I linked sketches out microbenchmarking in general.  I'm not able to do justice to all this in the space of comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now think I understand the semantics of LD. Do you know if ST operations are similar, i.e. can they return before the destination is written? Put another way, can an ST cause a warp stall?

Comment: ST are "fire and forget" also.  However a warp could stall on an ST instruction if it were *not issuable*.  Since an ST instruction has a register as its source operand, if the contents of that register are not "ready", the warp could/would stall on that ST instruction, waiting for the source register contents to be ready.  But once ready, the ST instruction can be issued and is "fire and forget" at that point.  There isn't anything about the register data being deposited in global memory that would hold anything else up, further.